# Flutter: distinguish between wrong address and no connection

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

How can I distinguish at runtime if the mobile has no connection to internet or if I'm trying to reach a no existing URL address?

In both cases I'm getting the same error from Flutter: `Socket Exception with Failed host lookup: 'address'.`

Comment: You really can't.  "lacking permissions" often looks exactly like "doesn't exist", by design.  However, you can try connecting to well-known points, like google.com or example.com, to see if it's just your internet.